# What do the LargeChange and SmallChange properties do for a ProgressBar control?

Tags: wpf, properties, progress-bar

I'm currently studying for the Microsoft.NET Framework 3.5 - Windows Presentation Foundation exam. In the book I have (by Matthew A Stoeckler) it says this about these properties:

```
LargeChange
  Represents the amount added to or subtracted from the Value property when a
  large change is required
SmallChange
  Represents the amount added to or subtracted from the Value property when a
  small change is required
```

I have no idea what it could mean for a progress bar.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[LargeChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange.aspx) and [SmallChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.smallchange.aspx) don't apply to [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) - they are inherited from [RangeBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.aspx) and are used in [ScrollBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar.aspx).

They are used to determine (for the scrollbar at least) by how far to scroll if the user clicks the arrows at the end of the scroll bar (SmallChange) or the background of the ScrollBar either side of the slider (LargeChange)

Comment: I thought this would be it. These properties are mentioned in a table in the book that the author described as 'Important properties of the _ProgressBar_ control are shown...'. Apparently I have a different understanding of the word 'important'.

Comment: Yes, the book is pretty sloppy.

Answer (score 3):

More specifically, the LargeChange and SmallChange are specifically called out in this MSDN article as not applying to the ProgressBar:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange.aspx)

Apparently, this still hasn't made it into the book as of the .NET 4 version, which is the one I am reading now.